# launch program through shadowsocks

Tags: 14.04, proxy

I have used http proxy like: `export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:port programname`  to run program through http proxy.
How to launch program through shadowsocks?

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to use proxychains to run program through proxy.

*https://github.com/clowwindy/shadowsocks/wiki/Using-Shadowsocks-with-Command-Line-Tools*

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool named tsocks. In ubuntu, you can just install it by

```
apt-get install -y tsocks
```

then you can change the settings in `/etc/tsocks`, for example here is mine:

```
server=127.0.0.1
server_port=1080
server_type=5
```

`server_port` should match your shadowsocks's local port setting, `server_type` should be set to 5 because shadowsocks use socks5 not socks4.

then you can just run a program like:

```
tsocks <Your Command>
```

for example, you can type:

```
tsocks apt-get update
```